# Linux: manually set geographic position

Tags: debian, geolocation

I have a desktop workstation running Linux (Debian Sid, if relevant).
It does not have GPS or other specific means to get its own geographic location (Gnome Maps correctly places it in Rome, Italy, with an error of about 11.5 Mi!).

Is there some way I can just tell it where it's placed?

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/733559/is-it-possible-to-provide-local-geolocation-data), but it deals only with browser-based applications.
I would like to  override default positioning (i.e.: the same thing Gnome Maps used to get it's rough data).

Comment: Hmm. Most people don't want their exact location known ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I do understand, but this is my personal PC and not a generic server and I know quite well where it is. Should I be worried this info could be leaked to the Internet at large? if so by which means it could happen? This obviously has nothing to do with the question, I'm just being curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux does not have a 'standard' geographic position API – some programs get summarized data from *geoclue* (part of GNOME), while others talk to GPS/GNSS/Wi-Fi devices on their own (duplicating what geoclue does).

GNOME Maps always gets its position from the Geoclue daemon. Lacking GPS, Geoclue gets its approximate location based on 1) your IP address, and 2) your nearby Wi-Fi networks (which it submits to Mozilla's location service, but can use Google's if an API key is given). Since you don't have Wi-Fi either, it's all down to wherever the IP geolocation database thinks you are.

Currently Geoclue [does not](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/issues/51) have a parameter to set a fixed location. Your remaining options are:

- Hack the Geoclue source code to always return a fixed answer.
- Replace the Geoclue daemon itself with a custom one (written in Python or any other language that has decent D-Bus API bindings), and make it always return a fixed answer.
- Make Geoclue think there is a GPS device connected, by installing the *gpsd* daemon and using the included [gpsfake](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsfake.html) tool (see below).
- <del>Change the Mozilla location service URL in Geoclue to point at a custom webservice that always returns a fixed answer.</del> (This was mentioned in the Bugzilla thread, but since you don't have any Wi-Fi hardware, I don't think Geoclue will even bother asking the MLS in the first place...)
- Add a Wi-Fi adapter so that Geoclue could scan for nearby networks and map them to your location via Mozilla Location Service (this also needs NetworkManager).

For programs which don't use Geoclue but have GPS support by directly talking to *gpsd* (such as Firefox), you can use [gpsfake](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsfake.html) to make it pretend there is always a GPS sensor connected. However, it doesn't have simple options to specify the coordinates – you'll need to give it the captured output of a real GPS device, possibly hand-edited to have the correct coords.

Comment: I never said I don't have a WiFi adapter. In fact my workstation is connected to my home network via Wireless (802.11/ac). Does that open other possibilities?

Comment: I thought you included that in "a desktop with no other specific means to find its own location". If you see Geoclue querying the Mozilla Location Service, try MozStumbler on Android to submit more accurate location data, or switch it to Google Location Service.